# SQL - how to SUM two Count Statements to create a Total Column

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

i have the following query and for the life of me have forgotton how to SUM both columns to create a 'Total' column

```
SELECT username as 'username',
    count (case when casestype <> 'car'
        OR casestype <> 'van' 
        OR casestype  <> 'bike' 
        OR casestype  <> 'NONE' 
        THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'non-auto',
    count (case when casestype = 'car'
        OR casestype= 'van' 
        OR casestype  = 'bike' 
        THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'auto'
FROM Case WITH (NOLOCK)               
WHERE CaseDate BETWEEN '01  may 2016' AND '31 may 2016') 
GROUP BY username
```

I want to have a total column of non-auto + auto

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: After "left outer join" there is no table. Please fix that first.

Comment: Your posted query doesnt work.please add more info. please see here on how to start asking:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT username,
       sum(case when casestype not in ('car', 'van', 'bike', 'NONE')
                then 1 else 0
           end) as non_auto,
       sum(case when casestype in ('car', 'ban', 'bike') then 1 else 0
           end) as auto,
       sum(case when casestype <> 'NONE' then 1 else 0 end) as total
FROM [Case]                   
WHERE CaseDate BETWEEN '2016-05-01' and '2016-05-31'
GROUP BY username;
```

Additional advice:

- `in` and `not in` are much more readable than a series of `or` statements.
- Use ISO standard date formats.   YYYY-MM-DD is my preference, although SQL Server has a slight preference for YYYYMMDD.
- The `total` needs to be calculated separately.  If you want to use column aliases you need subqueries or CTEs.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use them for string and date constants.